# Webservice error on Delphi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, delphi

I trying make a **WebService** client on [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi), what receives a `String`, but when it get a response give an error

> error class EDOMParseError with message "Invalid at the top level of the document"
>   Line: 0
>   '.

My `String` is

```
'
I8,A,001
Q400,024
q863
rN
S3
D7
ZT
JF
O
R231,0
f100
N
A63,353,0,3,1,2,N,'www.zebrashop.com.br'
A17,10,0,3,2,2,N,'Linguagem EPL'
B43,123,0,1,2,6,160,B,'11 3526-5909'
P1
'
```

My [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) function is

```
procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var teste : impressao_port;
  xmld : TXMLDocument;
  i : Integer;
begin
  teste := Getimpressao_port();
  xmld := teste.imprimir;
  mmo1.Text := xmld.XML[0];
end;
```

I'm using [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) to server.

Comment: Can you post the delphi code you are using to access the webservice? Are you using a SOAP cliente on Delphi? Does your rails app returns just the string? For the error message delphi is expecting a XML and is getting a string instead.

Comment: I'm using, on Rails, WashOut gem, and default WSDL importer on delphi with SOAP. The codes are just test, on delphi are the same on IDE creates, and Rails are a sample of WashOut gem.

Comment: You're trying to use TXMLDocument on something that isn't XML. Why would you expect anything else but an error? TXMLDocument is for *working with XML*, which is why it has the name it does. It's not for just throwing text at randomly - it expects well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem must be in [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) application, this error occurs because you are trying to working in `XML` and the server is returning a `String`.